# Import CSV in Excel 2016 without PowerQuery

Tags: excel

I have used Excel for many years, but this PowerQuery is not helpfull in my day to day work. It lays on to much functionality not needed. I.E Automatic formating, connection to CSV file etc. It also have problems with decimal convertions.

In Excel 2013 I select Data - From text and i get a Text Import Wizard. 
But in 2016/365 I automatical get PowerQuery with wrong converts of numbers 7,87 (desimal sign is comma) - and values is handled as text.

Is there any option to turn of use of PowerQuery, and get back to Text Import Wizard instead?

Comment: Whilst you COULD, I'd suggest your time would be better spent learning to use Power Query to give the results you expect / need...

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible! The following is from [professor-excel.com](https://professor-excel.com/import-csv-text-files-excel/):

1. Go to File
2. Go to Options
3. Go to Data
4. Check all required legacy wizards, as shown in the image below.
5. The legacy wizard is now available under the tab `Data --> GetData`.

**Changing the Excel settings:**
[image: Change the Excel settings]

**Now the old text import wizard is available:**
[image: Now the old text import wizard is available]